# How can I flag or suggest edit or remove a tag created by other user?

Tags: discussion, tags

Is there any way to flag or suggest edit or remove a tag created by other user if that tag is found to be not useful or ambiguous?

Answer (score 3):

If you mean in one question, you can suggest your own edit, remove the tag but explain carefully why you're doing it. If three 2K users will agree, the tag will then be removed.

If you mean tag in general i.e. from all questions, post here on Meta explaining why, tag your request with [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and wait for other users input on this matter.

Comment: And be ready for (up-down)votes.

Comment: Is there any review on newly created tags?

Comment: Yes, Charles and a few others (including me occasionally) "review" all new tags.

Comment: @NK there is no official review but high rep users will take a look and remove the new tag if not appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to flag tags.

If you want to improve its tag-wiki then you can suggest tag-wiki from its *info* tab. If you think the tag is not useful or that it is ambiguous or it is not suitable for the site then just post a question on its Meta site to request for the removal.